# Python 3 xmlrpc for remote objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, remoteobject

I am trying to implement a remote object implementation using xmlrpc, and python 3.
I have tried the example at http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/xmlrpc.server.html?highlight=xmlrpc#simplexmlrpcserver-example, but it only works to and from localhost, how can I get it to work to and from internal IPs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question, but... Have you tried running the server code on another machine, and the client code (changing the 'localhost' value in the first line of the client code `s = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('http://localhost:8000')` to the IP address of the remote server?

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting? When the server is running on the remote computer, can you use a web browser to get a response at http://remote:8000 (or 'telnet remote 8000')?

Comment: You get the timeout even from a web browser? Sounds like it can't connect across the network... Things to check include firewalls (in between, or software firewalls on the server-side) and routing (can you even ping the server IP address from the client?).

Answer (score 1):

Update the localhost value to the following:

For the server : `s = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("ServerIp", 8000))`

For the client : `s = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy("http://ServerIp:8000/")`